# What is the safest way to display a pdf file sent over webRTC in a webpage?

Tags: pdf, iframe, webrtc, sandbox

I am making a WebRTC app that allows one user to send a .pdf file that is displayed in the 2nd user's browser. That bit is working fine by assigning the blob that is sent to an iframe's src attribute on the receiver's side.

I'm kind of leery of the combination of iframes, pdf and 3rd party content, so I have been experimenting with the sandbox attribute on the iframe.
But in sandboxing, the only way I can get an iframe to show the pdf using the browser's pdf plug-in is by setting

`sandbox="allow-scripts"`

but that seems to be doing exactly what I'm trying to avoid. As long as I only give the sandbox this permission, is that enough to mitigate the possibility of a malicious pdf doing something undesirable in the receiver's browser? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: "I'm kind of leery of the combination of iframes, pdf and 3rd party content," could you elaborate on what you mean here? WebRTC is peer to peer, so seems pretty secure. What exactly are you worried about?

Comment: My concern is with peer A sending peer B a pdf with malicious JavaScript in it that will then just run unhindered in peer B's browser. The question really is if that's an unavoidable risk or if in fact it is that risky at all.

Comment: It will be as risky as the tech used to display the pdf.